# How should wake turbulence from aircraft on the ground be avoided during landing?

Tags: general-aviation, student-pilot, cessna-172, wake-turbulence, cessna-152

If a large jet aircraft is holding short of runway 28L while I am landing a single-engine aircraft on runway 28R, how should I proceed with such a landing?

Comment: It depends if the large jet aircraft is landing or taking off.

Comment: Some questions impacting your decision to land. Is the wind blowing from South? How distant are the runways? Have you been cleared for landing? Will the other a/c takeoff before you touch down? Are you IFR? Did ATC add a "Caution, wake turbulence" warning in the clearance? Can you touch down before being abeam the rotation point for the other a/c based on the relative positions of the thresholds? See FAA [Pilot and ATC Guide to Wake Turbulence](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/training/media/wake/04SEC2.PDF).

Answer (score 10):

Wake turbulnce occurs when an aircraft is creating lift.  Since, the airliner is on the ground, there is no wake turbulence.

If you are worried about jet blast from the airliner holding short between the runways, then I would land past the airliner by about 1000 ft.  With the airliners engines at idle, there will be minimal jet blast but if the increase power that jet blast increases significantly.